# What would the truth table for a finite state machine showing transitions of flags in a nascar race look like?

Tags: finite-automata

I'm trying to construct a truth table from a finite state machine of flags in a NASCAR race.

Flag meanings: green=start yellow=caution red=stop black=get off white=one lap left checkered=finish line

In an example with a stoplight in class, the variable that makes the current state go to the next state on the stoplight is a timer. So the truth table looked like this:

```
Timer    current state    next state
0            red              red
1            red              green
0            green            green
1            green            yellow
etc...
```

For a NASCAR Flag FSM would the variable be whatever is causing it to go to next state, since there isn't a timer involved(?)?

For example, would this be correct?

```
variable      current state            next state
crash             green                     yellow
stop race         green                     red
get off track     green                     black
1 lap left        green                     white
race over         white                     checkered
```

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Your transition table is incomplete.